# Windows App Certification Kit 10.0 não funciona

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10

Eu estou com um problema para enviar meu aplicativo Windows 10 para a loja. A ferramenta que executa depois de dar o deploy do app, fica preso em "cortar após suspensão do Direct3D" e "Codificação de arquivo UTF 8",  alguem já passou por isso, o que devo fazer?

[image: Validação do Aplicativo não termina e está presa nesse processo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, o erro era na minha maquina. O Anti-virus Comodo estava bloqueando o processo de certificação. Mesmo com ele totalmente desabilitado, eu não estava conseguindo fazer essa etapa. Então, tive que desinstala-lo completamente para fazer essa etapa. 
Obrigado a todos que leram e pensaram em como solucionar isso.